# Getting text overflow to work without overlapping

Tags: html, css

This is my php code, that is using echo html

```
echo "<li style='width:" . $iw . "px;height:" . $ih . "px;overflow:hidden;font-size:" .     $ifo . "px; margin:5px' onClick='playVideo($c,\"" . urlencode($f) . "\",\"$m\",\"$p2\", \""  . urlencode($d) . "\", \"$a\", $dur, $iwo, $iho,$scale)' id='li$c'>";
    echo "<div id='vidthumbnail' class='imgdesc'>
    <div id='vidinfo1' class='vidthumbclass'>
        <img style='margin-right: 5px; height: 20px; width: 20px' src='images/red.png'/>
        <text style='margin-right: 2px'> $d </text> 
        <text style='color: grey; font-weight: normal; position: relative; left: 20%'>$ph_days</text>
    </div>
    <div id='vidthumbicon'><img src='test.png' style=' width: 40px; height: 40px; vertical-align: auto' /></div>
    <div id='vidinfo2' class='vidthumbclass'>
        <img src='images/love.png'/>
        <text>$ph_loves</text>
        <img src='images/grey.png'/>
        <text>$ph_dislikes</text>
        <img src='images/sh.png'/>
        <text style='vertical-align: middle' >$ph_shares</text>
    </div>
  </div>"; // TODO do text overflow
echo "<img style='position:absolute;z-index:1;width:" . $iw . "px;height:" . $ih . "px;'     src='$p2' width=$iw height=$ih/>";
echo "</li>";
```

This is my css code, or at least the important part:

```
#vidthumbnail {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:200;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0%;
}

img {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left:2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

text {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.vidthumbclass {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6); 

    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left:  5px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#vidinfo1 { 
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#vidthumbicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 40%;
}

#vidinfo2 {  
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 80%;
}
```

I've been trying to get the text $d within the vidinfo1 div to overflow to an ellipsis when text is too long. It works, but it overflows at the end of the div, which means that the php string $d still overlaps with the string $ph_days$. I've been trying to get $d to overlap before the $ph_days text by setting the width of the $d text through html and through the text attribute in css, but it hasn't worked.

How can I get the string to overlap between the text?

Answer (score 0):

```
.front-div {
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.back-div {
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What do these front and back divs represent?